# problem with clone() - events

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

i have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/eKZK3/):

What reason the new cloned div is not associated to:

```
        $("#one2 .area").change(function(){  
            alert('changedTwo');  
        });
```

i dynamically generate a new id. The first cloned object is: `div id="one2"`

How i can fix that?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that the element didn't exist when the event-handlers were bound, on document ready. To test, you could change to:

```
$("#one2 .area").live('change', function(){  
        alert('changedTwo');  
    });
```

Reference:

- [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: @user455318: you're more than welcome; glad to have been of help :)